# Euler–Maclaurin formula: Mismatched dimensions

Tags: integration, physics, dimensional-analysis, euler-maclaurin

To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula):

> If ${\displaystyle m}$ and ${\displaystyle n}$ are natural numbers and ${\displaystyle f(x)}$ is a real or complex valued continuous function for real numbers ${\displaystyle x}$ in the interval ${\displaystyle [m,n]}$, then the integral
> $$ I = \int_m^n f(x)\,dx$$
> can be approximated by the sum (or vice versa)
> $$ S = f(m + 1) + \cdots + f(n - 1) + f(n) $$

My problem is, that I don't see how this can be a correct approximation. I stumbled across this doing dimensional analysis: $I$ has dimension $[f]\cdot[x]$ while $S$ has dimension $[f]$.

Is there something missing from the summation formula?

A more elaborate example from physics: If $\rho=\frac{dq}{dV}$ is the charge density, then the complete charge is given by $Q= \int dq = \int dV \rho(r)$. But the approximation $\sum_i\rho(x_i)$ will only be of dimension of the charge density, not the charge.

How to resolve this?

### Edit

As [@Randall](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/464495/randall) has pointed out in the comment, the sum should probably be

$$ S = \Delta x \sum_i f(x_i) \tag{1}$$

But what about the opposite direction? Let's say I start from this sum
$$ S = \sum_i f(x_i) \tag{2}$$
(without the $\Delta x$) and want to make an approximation by treating $x$ as a continuous variable. How would the integral look? I have seen some books and papers use $1/L$ where $L=\int_D dx$ over the domain of interest $D$.

Comment: They likely mean Riemann sums with $\Delta x =1$.  So multiply by $1$ unit to make the units right.

Comment: @Randall Yes, I think that's true. But what does that mean for the opposite direction? Suppose I have the sum and want to approximate it using an integral...

Comment: Go ahead and estimate.  But there is a good chance that $\Delta x =1$ gives a horrible approximation.

Comment: $f$ is a complex-valued function (possibly real-valued, but since $\mathbb{R}\subset \mathbb{C}$ that's included). The sum is a complex number, the integral is a complex number. There are no units/dimensions involved. If you want to interpret things in a dimensional (in the sense of physics) setting, yes, then you must multiply with the appropriate units.

Comment: @DanielFischer But suppose that $f = 1$. (2) gives me $N$, the number of discretization points, while the Integral gives me $L$. These are clearly not well defined, because if I increase $N$, i.e. make a finer approximation, (2) grows, while $L$ stays constant.

Comment: You don't get to choose the "discretization points". These are the integers from $m$ to $n$. (You can model picking other points by modifying $f$, but what you get is an application of the Euler-Maclaurin formula to a different function, with different $m$ and $n$, however the "discretization points" are again the integers in the interval.)